# Extract a list of distinct values from another list (remove dupes)

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, foreach, pgfmath

Suppose I have a list defined via `\def\zList{0,0,1,1,1,2,2,10}`.

How can I obtain a (comma-separated) list `0,1,2,10` that contains the unique/distinct values in `0,0,1,1,1,2,2,10`?

*Is there perhaps a way with `pgfmath`?* (I also need the whole thing in more complex contexts [pgfplots/-table], so `pgfmath` wouldn't be so bad ...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\zList{0,0,1,1,1,2,2,10}

\let\List=\empty% create List
\foreach \n  in \zList {%
\pgfmathparse{\n}%  <--- A clever method needed here
  \ifx\empty\List{} \xdef\List{\pgfmathresult}%
  \else \xdef\List{\List,\pgfmathresult}%
  \fi}
  
Show Zero List: \zList

Show List-Actual: \List

Show List-Target: 0,1,2,10
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not being an anglophone, I don't know whether or not one can say `diffent` for `different`, but what is it really?

Comment: If you have `\def\one{1}` - shall `1` and `\one` be considered the same within `\zList`? I.e., what shall the target-list look like with `\def\zList{1,\one}` ? Shall it be `1`? Shall it be `\one`? Shall it be `1,\one`? Shall it be `\one,1`?

Comment: @UlrichDiez I don't know, what you want to tell me or want to discuss with me. I have {0,0,1,1,1,2,2,10}. I need {0,1,2,10}. I think that is a sufficient description.

Comment: @cis Do all values in your list come as digit-sequences or do some of them come as expandable macro-tokens (plus arguments) whose expansion at some stage yields digit-sequences? In other words: Do you wish to compare numbers after full evaluation? Or is comparing comma-separated sets of tokens sufficient?

Comment: not being a programmer , if there is no direct command I see:
sorting and throw away numbers you already have. if the original sequence must be kept, then sort a copy and delete the doubles found in the sorted copy also in the original list

Comment: Will the arguments of `\zList` always be numbers, or could they be strings?

Comment: @Mico In my case (integer) numbers, but interesting idea to enlarge that by strings.

Comment: @cis - Thanks for this clarification. Please check out the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560514/5001) I posted earlier today. It can handle integers, strings consisting of comma-separated integers, and even macros that expand to (strings containing) integers. Moreover, the inputs don't have to be in ascending order. It would be trivially easy to modify the code to handle outright strings rather than integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could remove duplicates using `expl3`

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \removeclistdupes \clist_remove_duplicates:N
\ExplSyntaxOff
\Removeclistdupes\List
```

A full example

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \removeclistdupes \clist_remove_duplicates:N
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\zList{0,0,1,1,1,2,2,10}

\let\List=\empty% create List
zList
\foreach \n  in \zList {%
\pgfmathparse{\n}%  <--- A clever method needed here
  \ifx\empty\List{} \xdef\List{\pgfmathresult}%
  \else \xdef\List{\List,\pgfmathresult}%
  \fi}
\removeclistdupes\List
  
Show Zero List: \zList

Show List-Actual: \List

Show List-Target: 0,1,2,10
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

*Edit: Someone asked to have "unnecessary" zeros clipped. You can do this with `\FPclip` from the fp-package.*

If you wish to do the sorting-out with the tools provided by `tikz`, you can consider nested iteration on the already constructed list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

% pgfmanual.pdf promises a ot of things to work which often don't due to bugs.
% E.g., with tikz/pgf 3.1.1 by default there is no \ifpgfmathfloatparseactive
% and evaluation of if-expressions via \pgfmathfloattofixed seems corrupted.
% \newif\ifpgfmathfloatparseactive
% \pgfmathfloatparseactivefalse
%
% Afaik current release (the date of writing this answer is 
% August 28, 2020) is 3.1.5b.
% Seems things are fixed there.

\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newif\ifalreadyinserted

\begin{document}

\newcommand\one{1}
\newcommand\two{2}
\newcommand\onecommaeight{1.8}
\newcommand*\zList{0,0,1,1,1.8,1.6754376,\one,\two,1,2,4+4,2,10,1.7,1.7,\onecommaeight,8,1.0}

\newcommand*\List{}% create List
\foreach \n  in \zList {%
    \pgfmathparse{\n}%
    \let\n=\pgfmathresult
    \FPclip{\n}{\n}%
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\List}{%
      \def\List{}%
      \global\alreadyinsertedfalse
      \foreach \o in 
    }{%
      \tikzmath{%
        if (\o <= \n) then {{\xdef\List{\List\ifx\List\empty\else,\fi\o}};}%
                      else {{\xdef\List{\List\ifx\List\empty\else,\fi\ifalreadyinserted\else\n,\fi\o}};};%
        if (\o >= \n) then {{\global\alreadyinsertedtrue};};%
      }%
    }%
    \ifalreadyinserted\else
      \xdef\List{\List\ifx\List\empty\else,\fi\n}%
    \fi
}
  
Show Zero List: \texttt{\frenchspacing\string\zList: \meaning\zList}

Show List-Actual: \texttt{\frenchspacing\string\List: \meaning\List}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation:

You have the *⟨list passed by the user⟩* (`\zList`) and the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩* (`\List`).

With each element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩* do the following:

- Set a flag (`\ifalreadyinserted`/`\alreadyinsertedfalse`/`\alreadyinsertedtrue`) to indicate that there might be need to insert that element `\n` into the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩*.
- "Look" at each element `\o` of the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩* for finding out if the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩* needs to be inserted into the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩* :

  As long as the value of the element `\o` of the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩* is not greater than the value of the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩*, the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩* does not need to be inserted into the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩*.

  **If, while the flag still indicates that there might be need to insert the element `\n` into the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩*, it occurs the first time** that the value of the element `\o` of the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩* is greater than the value of the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩*, the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩* needs to be inserted into the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩* before the element `\o` of the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩*.
  *If it occurs the first time...—the flag is needed for finding out if it is the first time.*

  If the value of the element `\o` of the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩* is greater than or equal to the value of the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩*, then the flag needs to be set to indicate that there is no need to insert the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩* into the *⟨list passed by the user⟩*.
- If after looking at all elements `\o` of the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩* the flag still indicates that there might be need to insert the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩* into the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩*, then this indicates that the value of the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩* is greater than the values of all elements `\o` that are already in the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩* and that therefore the element `\n` of the *⟨list passed by the user⟩* needs to be appended to the *⟨sorted list created so far⟩*.

Comment: Can you give your algorithm in pseudocode? Or in another way, but the main thing is that everyone can understand your algorithm even if they misunderstand the TeX code?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,pgffor}
\newcounter{zcount}
\newtoks\mytoks
\mytoks{}
\expandafter\def\csname zmatch0\endcsname{-9999999}% NUMBER NOT IN LIST
\begin{document}
\def\zList{0,0,1,1,1,2,2,10}
The original list is \zList

\readlist\zdata{\zList}
\foreachitem\z\in\zdata[]{%
  \gdef\ztest{F}%
  \foreach\zcnt in {0,...,\thezcount}{%
    \ifnum\z=\csname zmatch\zcnt\endcsname\relax\gdef\ztest{T}\fi%
  }%
  \if F\ztest
    \stepcounter{zcount}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname zmatch\thezcount\expandafter\endcsname
      \expandafter{\z}%
    \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\the\mytoks\relax
      \else\mytoks\expandafter{\the\mytoks,}\fi
    \mytoks\expandafter{\the\expandafter\mytoks\z}%
  \fi
}
The new list is \the\mytoks
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are not comfortable with token lists, then here is a version that uses `\def`s, instead

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,pgffor}
\newcounter{zcount}
\expandafter\def\csname zmatch0\endcsname{-9999999}% NUMBER NOT IN LIST
\begin{document}
\def\zList{0,0,1,1,1,2,2,10}
The original list is \zList

\readlist\zdata{\zList}
\foreachitem\z\in\zdata[]{%
  \gdef\ztest{F}%
  \foreach\zcnt in {0,...,\thezcount}{%
    \ifnum\z=\csname zmatch\zcnt\endcsname\relax\gdef\ztest{T}\fi%
  }%
  \if F\ztest
    \stepcounter{zcount}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname zmatch\thezcount\expandafter\endcsname
      \expandafter{\z}%
    \ifnum\thezcount=1\relax
      \xdef\zNewList{\csname zmatch1\endcsname}%
    \else
      \xdef\zNewList{\zNewList,\csname zmatch\thezcount\endcsname}
    \fi
  \fi
}

The new list is \zNewList
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

The input string -- defined by, say, `\zList` -- may contain numbers, macros (except `\zList` itself) that expand to numbers, and strings that contain a list of comma-separated numbers. The numbers needn't be sorted in ascending order.

`\unique` extracts the unique sorted numbers contained in `\zList`.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function string_to_table (str)
   local fields = {} -- initialize the table
   str:gsub( "([^,]*)" , function ( c ) 
                 -- strip off anyleading and trailing whitespace:
                 c = c:gsub ( "^%s*(.-)%s*$" , "%1" )
                 -- insert 'c' in 'fields'
                 table.insert ( fields , tonumber(c) )   
               end )
   return fields
end
function remove_duplicate_entries ( t ) 
   -- from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20067270/1014365
   local hash = {}
   local res = {}
   for _,v in ipairs(t) do
      if (not hash[v]) then
         res[#res+1] = v 
         hash[v] = true
      end
   end
   return res
end
function unique ( s )
   local t
   -- Convert string 's' to a Lua table:
   t = string_to_table ( s )
   -- Sort the table entries in ascending order:
   table.sort ( t , function(a,b) return a<b end)
   -- Retain the unique elements:
   t = remove_duplicate_entries ( t )
   -- Convert table back to string and print:
   tex.sprint ( table.concat ( t, "," )  )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% LaTeX-side code:
\newcommand\unique[1]{\directlua{unique(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\def\mynum{10}
\newcommand\mystr{"\mynum,0"}
\def\zList{0,10,1,1,2,2,1,0,\mynum,\mystr}

\zList

\unique{\zList}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, the site software has informed me that this is answer #6,666 I've posted on this site joining a bit more than 9 years ago. I had no idea!